# Remove Jargon but keep real characters

Tags: javascript, html

I"m getting bombarded by spam with posts like below, so what would be the best and most efficient way of remove all the jargon from something like this:

```
<texarea id="comment">ȑ̉̽ͧ̔͆ͦ̊͛̿͗҉̷̢̧̫̗̗͎͈͕e̷̪͓̼̼̣̻̻͙͔̳̘̗͙̬̱͎ͭ̃͗ͩͯͥͬ̂ͧ͐͌̑̅͢͜ͅd̴̦̺̖̣͎̲̥͕̗̺̯̤͗ͬ͌ͧ̓͒ͭ́̋ͩͥ͊̇̓̌ͫ̃́́͠</textarea>
```

I'm assuming RegEx, but what exactly are those things called and how would it be referenced in RegExp? The problem lays within a `<textarea>` tag, and upon retrieving the value, I'd like to be able to remove all that jargon from the value and have it only display the real characters which in this case should be `red`.

Allowing other Unicode type of characters are essential, but not characters that stack on top of each other.

Comment: You just *destroyed* the question page, man :P

Comment: (Also I don't see any red characters in that... thing)

Comment: @Adrian Wow, just noticed that after I posted. Removed the jargon from the title. :3

Comment: Sadly, those combining characters is how many clients will construct their `ü` and `ç` characters.

Comment: Wait! You said you removed the jargon from the title. Please explain, what do you mean by "jargon"?

Comment: @q-l-p I had previously used the special characters in the title of this post, and this inadvertently caused display issues on the  Stackoverflow site.

Comment: So, the term "jargon" means "special characters that cause display issues"? Is this programming terminology? What is your native language? This is very interesting to me because it seems you use the word "jargon" in a jargonic way, which would be awesome. Is this usage of the word "jargon" normal in programming circles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zalgo waits behind the wall.

You want to filter out combining characters, such as the diacritical marks listed [here](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3aBlock=Combining_Diacritical_Marks%3a%5D).

You should be able to get away with a simple character class pattern match, *i.e.*:

`fooString.replace(/[\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0489\u1dc0-\u1dff\u20d0-\u20ff\ufe20-\ufe2f]/, "");`

If you want to limit content to one combination per character (not that this really alleviates all negative side-effects), you could simply use

`fooString.replace(/([\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0489\u1dc0-\u1dff\u20d0-\u20ff\ufe20-\ufe2f])[\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0489\u1dc0-\u1dff\u20d0-\u20ff\ufe20-\ufe2f]*/, "$1");`

EDIT: Added a number of other combining character ranges.  This is most likely still not exhaustive.

Comment: A list of characters is here http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[%3aBlock=Combining_Diacritical_Marks%3a]

Comment: This almost works (I'm not sure what the `s/` is supposed to be doing) Here is what I tried: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/PfXpn/

Comment: Ah, my bad.  That's simply Perl regex notation for substitution - the equivalent of JS `.replace`.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work as intended for salvaging the first diacritical in each sequence.  You would want to use "$1" as your second argument to replace.  This will replace the entire sequence with the contents captured between the `()` - that is, the first character of the sequence.

Comment: Updated my answer to use JavaScript string substitution instead of raw regex notation.

Comment: @chomp Just about there, having an issue with `r҉` for some reason though, and I don't see it on the list (on the one you gave the link to)

Comment: Ah.  There are a few other ranges of combining characters which you could add to your character class.  Things will start to get ugly, but I will update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Removing combining diacriticals will make input of some languages (such as Vietnamese) difficult or impossible, so you should reconsider.

Comment: So that's what they are called. Though, there must be a way to only allow one of those for a given character?

Comment: Sometimes two or three may be required in order to compose a character.